# how to load a partial view as a Modal in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have  a partial view (in a haml file ). is it possible to load this as a Modal, when the page this contains loads, may be via javascript?

```
#content
  .left.column
    %p= some content
```